# Unable to set autologin on Pi Zero W running Raspbian Buster lite, previous solutions ineffective

Tags: boot-issues, raspi-config, systemd, raspbian-lite, raspbian-buster

Upon setting boot options to autologin to console in my pi zero, it still asks for the username/password after reboot. I tried following the advice of this fourm post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=127042 but to no avail. I keep getting these warnings when booting, which I'm thinking may be related to my problem, but googling them turns up little so I'm not entirely convinced that they're not just part of the normal systemd spiel:

```
[    6.308696] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    6.337160] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    6.365338] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[    8.565984] systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
```

I tried booting from a new SD card to see if corruption was to blame but I got the same results. The image was burned through balenaEtcher on a windows machine and communication with the pi is being done over serial. I am using the latest version of raspbian as of the writing of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a *Pi Zero W* but I verified the problem with *Raspbian Buster Light* on a *Raspberry Pi 4B* and can confirm that autologin enabled with `sudo raspi-config` does not work on the serial debug console.

The problem is that there are different services for the **hdmi** attached tty and the serial console. The former is managed with `getty@tty1.service` the latter with `serial-getty@ttyS0.service`, so you have to enable autologin on the right service.

Just modify the right service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

Reboot and it should do.